# How do I modify the values of objects contained in arrays in MongoDB documents

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

data format is as follows:

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "$oid" : "5ece2f6babf1d6139784d85f"
  },
  "parentId" : "5e4f452ea94a510ef590f84c",
  "description" : "",
  "attribute" : {
    "timeInterval" : "10",
    "logSpace_unit" : "m",
    "events" : [{
        "formDate" : "08-11",
        "toDate" : "10-31",
        "startTime" : "11:45",
        "stopTime" : "23:59",
        "weekDays" : ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "_", "_"],
        "isTime" : 2,
        "period" : "day"
      }]
  }
}
```

I attempted to modfiy it by doing the following 'formDate' value

```java
mongoTemplate.upsert(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(triggerObjectId)),
                                   new update().addToSet("attribute.events.formDate",formDate),TreeNode.class);
```

but there was a problem:

```java
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Cannot create field 'formDate' in element {events: [ { formDate: "08-11", toDate: "10-31", startTime: "11:45", stopTime: "23:59", weekDays: [ "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "_", "_" ], isTime: 2, period: "day" } ]}
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1033)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1015)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:635)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:524)
    ... 17 more
```

I try to modify the condition to complete the modification of the object, but still failed

```
attribute.events.$.formDate
```

what can i do to solve this problem?
hope you help me.
thank U.           :)

Comment: `addToSet` only works with sets.  If you are trying to replace the string, use `set`

Comment: i use  set   update data,but final result and addToSet exception  information same TAT